# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined - updateListBox

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have developed Jenkins-plugin and stuck with an error. The plugin works fine in Jenkins version - 2.7.3 but, not on the higher or latest versions of Jenkins.

stacktrace on chrome console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined
at updateListBox (select.js:8)
at select.js:79
at h (hudson-behavior.js:1295)
at refillOnChange (hudson-behavior.js:1310)
at select.js:77
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at behavior.js:111
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at behavior.js:107
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

config.jelly would look like below

```
<f:entry field="configName" title="Choose Configuration Name">
   <table>
     <tr><td><f:select name="config_name" id="config_name" 
  onchange="updateListBox('team_info','descriptorByName/org.jenkinsci.plugins.ctc.TestAutomationBuilder/teamInfo?value='+encode(this.value))"/></td>
     <td><f:textbox disabled="true" name="config_name_name" default="${instance.getConfig_name()}"/></td></tr>
   </table>
  </f:entry>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I've got the same problem

Comment: working on a pull request for the fix to this problem. [https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/pull/3645]